# Dataframe is not displaying whole table

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I am not sure why it is displaying only the last column in dataframe instead of all the rows in beautified_value

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://www.worldometers.info/world-population/population-by-country/'

output = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(output.text, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find_all('table')
table = table[0]
columns = []

header_tags = table.find_all('th')

headers = [header.text.strip() for header in header_tags]
data_rows = table.find_all('tr')

for row in data_rows:
   value = row.find_all('td')
   beautified_value = [dp.text.strip() for dp in value]
#print(beautified_value)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[beautified_value], columns=[headers])
```

Comment: You're assigning `beautified_value` a fresh value every time through the loop, which discards the previous value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not appending values to `beautified_value`, just rewriting it over and over. You can use `list.append`, for example:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.worldometers.info/world-population/population-by-country/"

output = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(output.text, "html.parser")

table = soup.find("table")
columns = []

header_tags = table.find_all("th")

headers = [header.text.strip() for header in header_tags]
data_rows = table.find_all("tr")[1:]

beautified_value = []
for row in data_rows:
    value = row.find_all("td")
    beautified_value.append(dp.text.strip() for dp in value)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=beautified_value, columns=headers)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
       #   Country (or dependency) Population (2020) Yearly Change  Net Change Density (P/Km²) Land Area (Km²) Migrants (net) Fert. Rate Med. Age Urban Pop % World Share
0      1                     China     1,439,323,776        0.39 %   5,540,090             153       9,388,211       -348,399        1.7       38        61 %     18.47 %
1      2                     India     1,380,004,385        0.99 %  13,586,631             464       2,973,190       -532,687        2.2       28        35 %     17.70 %
2      3             United States       331,002,651        0.59 %   1,937,734              36       9,147,420        954,806        1.8       38        83 %      4.25 %

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `read_html`. Not that I had to set the user agent manually with requests, otherwise it would throw a `403` error:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html(requests.get(url,headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}).text)[0]
```

|  | # | Country (or dependency) | Population (2020) | Yearly Change | Net Change | Density (P/Km²) | Land Area (Km²) | Migrants (net) | Fert. Rate | Med. Age | Urban Pop % | World Share |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | China | 1439323776 | 0.39 % | 5540090 | 153 | 9388211 | -348399 | 1.7 | 38 | 61 % | 18.47 % |
| 1 | 2 | India | 1380004385 | 0.99 % | 13586631 | 464 | 2973190 | -532687 | 2.2 | 28 | 35 % | 17.70 % |
| 2 | 3 | United States | 331002651 | 0.59 % | 1937734 | 36 | 9147420 | 954806 | 1.8 | 38 | 83 % | 4.25 % |
| 3 | 4 | Indonesia | 273523615 | 1.07 % | 2898047 | 151 | 1811570 | -98955 | 2.3 | 30 | 56 % | 3.51 % |
| 4 | 5 | Pakistan | 220892340 | 2.00 % | 4327022 | 287 | 770880 | -233379 | 3.6 | 23 | 35 % | 2.83 % |